# Using array.some function with async/await does not return all from array

Tags: javascript

I have an arbitrary array, and I want to perform async/await on each value in the array, and check if there is a true value for the returned boolen value.

```
const account = 'foo'
const exists = (async (log: Log) => {
    console.log(log)
    return (await library.dosome(log.doanother)).accout === account
})
logs.some(exists)
```

However, when I look at the `console.log` value in the above code, I see that it only passes the value of `logs[0]`.

Is there a way to solve these problems?

Comment: You can't use `await` inside an Array method (.some, .map, .forEach, etc). It doesn't work (doesn't await). You have to use a `for` loop

Comment: What does `(log: Log)` do? Looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: `some()` like all other array method `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.filter()`, etc only works synchronously. Passing an async callback means that the result is a promise, which, for methods that expect a boolean, means it's truthy.